# Problem with variadic template expansion in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, c++14, c++17

This code works nicely with gcc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <bool... Bs>
struct bool_sequence {};

template <bool... Bs>
using bool_and = std::is_same<
                            bool_sequence<Bs...>,
                            bool_sequence<(Bs || true)...>
                            >;
template <bool... Bs>
using bool_or = std::integral_constant<bool, !bool_and<!Bs...>::value>;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << bool_or<true>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << bool_or<true, true>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << bool_or<true, true, true>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Expected output: 1 1 1.
[Here live example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a6cc1c9a16ca29d)

But  VS 2017 outputs: 0 0 0. 
Is this a bug in VS or am I missing something here ?

**Edit:**  VS 2017, v141, cl: 19.16.27030.1

Thanks

Comment: Could you give more information about your compiler version? My test with vs 2017 on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/NQJi9t) doesn't reproduce the behavior.

Comment: @StoryTeller: VS 2017 proffessional, v141, cl: 19.16.27030.1

Comment: Aha. Considering it works in 19.14 I'd say you indeed encountered regression.

Comment: FYI, in case that's the actual code you are trying to compile and not a MVCE: `std::disjunction` and `std::conjunction` perform these same operations, and most certainly work under all these compiler versions.

Comment: @Frank: yes, std::conjunction and std::disjunction work straitfoward. But this is only MVCE and the question is why VS doesn't compile it correctly. The funny thing is that the Intellisense in VS is showing the expansion correctly, but the compiler does it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This doesnt answer my question directly, but is just a workaround (actually not really workaround, but much cleaner solution for the real code comparing to the MVCE above) using std::conjunction/disjunction as propoesed by @Frank in the comment, for the case that someone else lands here for the same reason.

This works on VS as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <bool... Bs>
using bool_and =
    std::conjunction<std::integral_constant<bool, Bs>...>;

template <bool... Bs>
using bool_or =
    std::disjunction<std::integral_constant<bool, Bs>...>;

int main()
{
    std::cout << bool_or<true>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << bool_or<true, true>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << bool_or<true, true, true>::value << std::endl;
}
```

and also [live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c9e7ab57776844e)

Answer (score 0):

Why not using c++17 [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <bool... Bs>
using bool_and = std::bool_constant<(Bs && ...)>;

template <bool... Bs>
using bool_or = std::bool_constant<(Bs || ...)>;

int main()
{
    std::cout << bool_or<true>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << bool_or<false, false>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << bool_and<true, false, true>::value << std::endl;
}
```